# Visual Studio Code extentions are empty

Tags: visual-studio, debian, visual-studio-code

I have installed VS Code on my Debian Jessie machine from official page as described [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux) and set up proxy settings as described [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/setup-overview#_proxy-server-support), however I can't see any extensions in extensions bar.

There are no errors in output.

What could possibly be the solution for this problem? At least, where does VS Code could write errors?

UPD:
Found [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/23164) topic on project's github page which seems to be related to this problem , and [solution](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/23164#issuecomment-290353433) in comments worked for me

```
code --install-extension ms-vscode.csharp
```

So it seems like bug in Version 1.11.2

Comment: Have a look at View-->Problems & View--> Output to get an idea what would possibly be wrong.

Comment: @AbdullahLeghari , thanks, that Output window is silent